# Place one SVG element on top of another when using a non proportional viewbox

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this SVG:

```
<svg id="root" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="347.27mm" viewBox="0 0 409.32783 1230.3321" width="115.48mm" version="1.1">
  <circle id="b1" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" class="bottom" />
  <circle id="b2" cx="120" cy="100" r="15" class="bottom" />
  <g transform="translate(17,43)">
    <circle id="b3" cx="240" cy="200" r="15" class="bottom" />
    <circle id="b4" cx="360" cy="300" r="15" class="bottom" />
  </g>

  <!--      <g transform="translate(10,20)"> -->
  <circle id="t1" cx="80" cy="30" r="15" class="top" />
  <circle id="t2" cx="130" cy="30" r="15" class="top" />
  <!--        <g transform="translate(10,20)"> -->
  <circle id="t3" cx="180" cy="30" r="15" class="top" />
  <circle id="t4" cx="230" cy="30" r="15" class="top" />
  <!--    </g> -->
  <!--      </g> -->
</svg>
```

After the red balls coordinates are changed by the code that follows. It renders as:

[image: Rendered SVG]

I want to center the red balls on top of the green ones. I have a solution that works if you remove the viewBox attribute in the SVG tag. But unfortunately I can't do that. However, this works if the viewBox isn't there:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("root");

for (var index = 1; index <= 4; index++) {
  var bottom = svg.getElementById("b" + index);
  var top = svg.getElementById("t" + index);

  var targetX = parseFloat(top.getAttribute("cx"));
  var targetY = parseFloat(top.getAttribute("cy"));

  var center = getElementCenter(svg, bottom);

  top.setAttribute("cx", parseFloat(center.x));
  top.setAttribute("cy", parseFloat(center.y));
}

function getTransformedCoords(x, y, matrix) {
  var transformedX = x * matrix.a + y * matrix.c + matrix.e;
  var transformedY = x * matrix.b + y * matrix.d + matrix.f;

  return {
    x: transformedX,
    y: transformedY
  };
}

function getElementCenter(svg, element) {
  var x, y, width = 0, height = 0;

  var boundingBox = element.getBBox();
  var centerX = boundingBox.x + (boundingBox.width / 2);
  var centerY = boundingBox.y + (boundingBox.height / 2);

  var out = getTransformedCoords(centerX, centerY, element.getCTM()); // getCTM affected by the viewport

  centerX = out.x;
  centerY = out.y;

  return {
    x: centerX,
    y: centerY
  };
}
```

My working theory is that this is because the viewBox hasn't got the same ratio as the viewport. But I don't know how to fix that.

*I want to use **plain JavaScript** to do this. Even if it would be nice to use a suitable library.*

**Questions:**

1. How can I make it work while keeping the viewBox?
2. Is it possible to make it account for the transformations in the green circles as well? I commented those out in the SVG, but it would be nice to have something solid that works when they're in there as well. But number 1 is enough for me to accept the answer.

JSFiddle if you want to try the code out: https://jsfiddle.net/kentl/gpqcdecx/

PS. Here's the CSS if you want to style it:

```
.top {fill:red;animation:fall 4s ease-in-out infinite;}
.bottom{fill:green;}
@keyframes fall {0%{opacity:0.0;}50%{opacity:1.0;}100%{opacity:0.0;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use getTransformToElement. For Chrome you'll need a [polyfill](http://jointjs.com/blog/get-transform-to-element-polyfill.html) though as it's no longer natively implemented there.

```js
// The goal is to place the red circles on top of the green ones

// Working theory:
//   The viewBox hasn't got the same ratio as the viewport, which affects the returned transformation, returning
//   a matrix with slightly larger numbers than 1 for scaling X and Y. As that matrix is used to convert from the
//   local coordinate space in the bottom element, into the global one used by the top element, the coordinates are
//   scaled up slightly.. But when those coordinates are set in the top element, they'll be affected AGAIN by the
//   same up-scaling. Making them become more and more off the further from 0,0 we come.

// Question:
// 1. How can that be fixed?
// 2. Only if it's not too hard: Uncomment the <g>'s in the SVG. How do we compensate for the affected top CTM as well?


console.clear();

var svg = document.getElementById("root");

for (var index = 1; index <= 4; index++) {
  var bottom = document.getElementById("b" + index);
  var top1 = document.getElementById("t" + index);

  var targetX = parseFloat(top1.getAttribute("cx"));
  var targetY = parseFloat(top1.getAttribute("cy"));

  var center = getElementCenter(svg, bottom);
  
  t = bottom.getTransformToElement(top1);

  top1.setAttribute("cx", parseFloat(center.x) + t.e);
  top1.setAttribute("cy", parseFloat(center.y) + t.f);
}

function getElementCenter(svg, element) {
  var x, y, width = 0, height = 0;

  var boundingBox = element.getBBox();
  var centerX = boundingBox.x + (boundingBox.width / 2);
  var centerY = boundingBox.y + (boundingBox.height / 2);

  return {
    x: centerX,
    y: centerY
  };
}
```

```css
.top {
  fill: red;
  animation: fall 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.bottom {
  fill: green;
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="root" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="347.27mm" viewBox="0 0 409.32783 1230.3321" width="115.48mm" version="1.1">
  <circle id="b1" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" class="bottom" />
  <circle id="b2" cx="120" cy="100" r="15" class="bottom" />
  <g transform="translate(17,43)">
    <circle id="b3" cx="240" cy="200" r="15" class="bottom" />
    <circle id="b4" cx="360" cy="300" r="15" class="bottom" />
  </g>

  <!--      <g transform="translate(10,20)"> -->
  <circle id="t1" cx="80" cy="30" r="15" class="top" />
  <circle id="t2" cx="130" cy="30" r="15" class="top" />
  <!--        <g transform="translate(10,20)"> -->
  <circle id="t3" cx="180" cy="30" r="15" class="top" />
  <circle id="t4" cx="230" cy="30" r="15" class="top" />
  <!--    </g> -->
  <!--      </g> -->
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I combine t.a to t.d in this case? I guess it's necessary if a rotation would have been involved?